# Can't scroll within scrollable area inside a Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal that has a scrollable area within the modal. If I scroll within the scrollable area, it scrolls perfectly. If I scroll outside of the scrollable area, nothing happens, which is correct.

The problem is that if I scroll outside of the scrollable area, and then quickly back in the scrollable area, the scrollable area doesn't scroll. 
See video here: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9kiPTnt4e0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9kiPTnt4e0)

In another video here: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=epansufGEuY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epansufGEuY) I have selected the .modal-backdrop div behind the modal in the web inspector, and scrolled outside the scrollable area in the modal, and as you can see the .modal-backdrop is still scrolling, but not to the naked eye. The same thing happens when I select the body - the body element acts the same way.

I think this is causing the issue, as once the momentum scroll has stopped, the user can then scroll in the scrollable area within the modal again, but if you scroll outside and then inside quickly afterwards, it still thinks you are scrolling the .modal-backdrop.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue. I have position:fixed and overflow:hidden on the body, which solved the 'backrgound scrolling when you scroll the modal' issue, but this issue is different and has stumped me.

Comment: Probably because scrolling/tapping outside the modal would make it loose it's focus state, try tapping back on modal after scrolling outside of it and see if that makes the modal scrollable again. Either way, if you shared the modal code it would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.modal-content {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a bug in Bootstrap, and it has been fixed in the latest Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5 build.